# Making an object move when it reaches the border

Tags: ms-access

We have an assignment for university, which in sense is simple enough. So here is what it is: By using macros, two buttons make a box move left and right respectively.
Although I got the left to work wonderfully, the move right button is giving problems. 
the box should stop when it reaches the border of the application but:

([Forms]![frmMain]![bxBlackBox].[left]+100)>[Forms]![frmMain].[Width]

does not work as a valid if statement condition. in this if statement the right button should then disable.

I would appreciate any input on what I need to use as a acceptable if statement so that the little box would stop as soon as it reaches the border.

Comment: You should post the rest of your code to help others see what exactly you are trying to accomplish, e.g. the code for the whole button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
(Forms!frmMain!bxBlackBox.Left + Forms!frmMain!bxBlackBox.Width) > Forms!frmMain.Width
```

instead. Those numbers are in Twips -- 567 Twips per cm, 1440 Twips per inch.
So 100 is less than 2 mm.

Comment: Thank you this was just what i needed. Thank you too for that piece of information too I did not know this.